# looping over <li> using ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net

I want to change the visibility of `<li>` collection throw server side.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li runat=server id="l1"></li>
    <li runat=server id="l2"></li> 
    <li runat=server id="l3"></li> 
    <li runat=server id="l4"></li> 
    ...
</ul>
```

Now as I said I want to loop over the collection and change the visibility of some li using their ID

something like

```
for (i=0;...) {
    l+I.visible=false
}
```

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Untested</strike>, but this could work:

First change, your `ul` to be running on the server.

```
<ul runat="server" id="myList">
```

Then iterate through it

```
foreach (Control li in myList.Controls)
{
      if(li is HtmlGenericControl)
         li.Visible = false;
}
```

Example Code:

Html:

```
  <ul runat="server" id="myList">
    <li runat=server id="l1">1</li>
    <li runat=server id="l2">2</li> 
    <li runat=server id="l3">3</li> 
    <li runat=server id="l4">4</li>        
  </ul>


  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Button Click Handler:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control li in myList.Controls)
    {
        if (li is HtmlGenericControl)
            li.Visible = false;

     } 
 }
```

EDIT 2 - 
Code in VB.NET

```
For Each li As Control In myList.Controls
    If TypeOf li Is HtmlGenericControl Then
        li.Visible = False

    End If
Next
```

Comment: @baaroz - What happens? I just tried it and it worked fine. I've updated my answer to show my test code.

Comment: @Baaroz, did you remember runat=server on the UL tag?

Comment: Just use: `foreach(var li in mystList.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>()) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     <ul>            
        <% for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){%>
         <li runat=server id="l<%Response.Write(i); %>"><%=i%></li> 
        <% } %>
     </ul>
```

just inside html page !